# How to develop for iphone 3.1.3 without re-downloading the whole SDK

Tags: iphone

I have downloaded the latest iphone SDK which support developing for the ipad 3.2 and iphone 3.1.2

However 2 days ago the firmware 3.1.3 has been released by apple so my question is how to make my SDK to support this new firmware without re-downloading the whole SDK which is more than 2 gigs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can install them to different paths. I recommend installing the 3.1.3 SDK to `/Developer` and the 3.2 SDK to `/Developer (Prerelease)`. Then, launch whichever version of Xcode you want to use.

Comment: That is how I am working and it works quite well (though I installed the 3.2 to /Developer-3.2)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simply symlink the 3.1.2 SDK to 3.1.3? I think that was advised in the past when a minor update came out.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is the additional tools, not the SDK that take up a large chunk of the 2.5GB+ download size. The official response is there are no SDK only downloads. So you're kind of stuck with the download.

If you're looking to try make 2 SDKs available to you at once, well that's a different question.

Comment: Thanks, my iPhone runs 3.1.3 and I cannot test my apps on my iphone because the SDK I have is 3.1.2, r u sure I have to download the whole  SDK package again

Comment: Yes, without the new 3.1.3 SDK, you can't build for a device using the 3.1.3 OS.
Symlinking an old SDK with a 3.1.3 alias may allow you to compile, but you're likely to run into problems with API compatibility, and you won't benefit from any of the bug fixes in the new SDK. This is why new SDK's are released.